# Won't signed measures upset Riemann?

Tags: measure-theory, fake-proofs, signed-measures

I can't seem to wrap my head around [signed measures](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Signed_measure#Definition).

If $\mu$ is a signed measure on a measurable space $(X, \Sigma)$, then there'll be sets of both positive and negative measure. Let $E_1, E_2, \ldots\in\Sigma$ be disjoint and set $E := \bigcup_i E_i$ which is also in $\Sigma$. Now, the definition requires that $\mu(E) = \sum_{i = 1}^\infty \mu(E_i)$. However, since there can be infinitely many terms, both positive and negative, it well may be that the sequence $\sum_{i = 1}^\infty \mu(E_i)$ converges *only conditionally*. Then Riemann says that you can rearrange the sequence to converge to any extended real! And this would mean that $\mu(E)$ is not just one value—which is nonsensical!

**Question:** What am I missing here?

Comment: From your wikipedia link "The series on the right must converge absolutely when the value of the left-hand side is finite."

Comment: @AlessandroCodenotti My bad! Somehow, my eyes decided to skip that vital nugget of info.

Comment: Measure theory is built on absolute convergence to avoid exactly Riemann rearrangement issues. The Riemann integral has a direction to it which means the areas are added in a specific way, so a conditionally convergent Riemann integral could be rearranged to give different values. Meaning, if we do smaller subintegrals, we can get different answers by adding them up differently. This is clearly not desirable if what we want is an area: it shouldn't matter how we add the area pieces. Thus the need for absolute convergence.

Comment: Rearranging the sequence $E_i$ does not affect the union so that the series converges indeed unconditionally and hence absolutely.

Comment: I doubt that Riemann used "extended" , I rather think he mentioned the possibility that the rearranged series diverges seperately.